# Intern 3.4.1 on IOS Safari "unable to set accept insecure certs on Safari"

Tags: ios, node.js, automated-tests, ssl-certificate, intern

I am trying to Run intern Scripts on IOS Safari I am doing automation for some internal company services...

On MAC Safari same automation worked after placing  certificates (with name  of server it directly worked by placing certificate , but when i changed server name with ip I again accepted the warning for accept insecure cert) ..

My assumption was same will work for IOS simulator running on Same machine ...
I tired to access (server on which web service is running with both name and ip but didn't work )

I tried by placing    "acceptInsecureCerts" : True  but I think it's only for firefox

Answer (score 0):

You can install certificates in the simulator using the `mobile: installCertificate` [Appium script](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/ios/ios-xctest-install-certificate/). Using it with Intern should look something like this:

```js
const cert = fs.readFileSync('certificate.cer');
const content = cert.toString('base64');
return this.remote.execute('mobile: installCertificate', [{ content }]);
```

Comment: sorry ... but where do I need to keep this code                                                                                              configuration file of intern i.e intern.js                                                                                         since we don't have access to functional scripts it will be written by automation team...

Comment: I have kept code in setup function , and when i execute script it show error cannot read property readFileSync of undefined ... I have kept certificates in /users/abc/certificate.cert ..... my code looks like                                             const setup:function (fs)                                                                                                 
 {    cert = fs.readFileSync('/users/abc/certificate.cer');
const content = cert.toString('base64');
return this.remote.execute('mobile: installCertificate', [{ content }]);},

Comment: The `fs` in the original code snippet is just the Node fs module, so you'll need to import that before you can use it. With the dojo loader, you would load it as `dojo/node!fs`.

Comment: Original error: Cannot parse common name value from the certificate. Is it valid and base64-encoded? Original error: Unknown encoding: latin-1}

Comment: Yes It's in PEM format   it starts with -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

Comment: still the issue is there

Comment: It looks like there's a [bug](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/10940) in some versions of Appium's XCUITest driver that may cause the issue you're experiencing. A fix was released in version 2.87.0 of the driver.

Comment: sorry ,but now there is next issue .

Comment: ] Plist file '/Users/admin/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/static/1mdnbdr.6q2jg.mobileconfig' does not exist. Returning an empty plist.
[debug] [BaseDriver] Waiting up to 0 ms for condition
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [POST /element] to [POST http://localhost:8100/session/816A6AC8-7B69-42B8-A6E8-888980AD554C/element] with body: {"using":"accessibility id","value":"Allow"}
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"value":{"using":"accessibility id","value":"Allow","description":"unable to find an element"}, UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning